# Checking for a perfect cube

Tags: python-3.x

So I have to make a code to check whether or not a number is a perfect cube, but for some reason for any cube greater than 27, it says it's root is x.99999999. (i.e. it returns 64**(1/3) as 3.9999 & 125**(1/3) as 4.9999).

```
n = int(input("What number would you like to check if it is a cube?"))

def is_cube(n):
    guess = n**(1.0/3.0)
    if (guess)%1 == 0:
        print(True, "it's cubed root is", guess)
    else:
        print(False, "it's cubed root is", guess)
is_cube(n)
```

Comment: Floats are not precise: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html Look into using the decimal module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#module-decimal

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just convert to an `integer` with `round` and check whether that `integer` `cubed` is the `input` (`n`).

```
def is_cube(n):
    cube_root = n**(1./3.)
    if round(cube_root) ** 3 == n:
        print(True, "its cubed root is", round(cube_root))
    else:
        print(False, "its cubed root is", cube_root)
```

And some tests:

```
>>> is_cube(12)
False its cubed root is 2.2894284851066637
>>> is_cube(34)
False its cubed root is 3.239611801277483
>>> is_cube(27)
True its cubed root is 3
>>> is_cube(64)
True its cubed root is 4
```

---

Oh and btw, the possessive form of `its` doesn't require an apostrophe. It's not right in your code.

Answer (score 2):

**Simple method to check perfect square and cube:**

**1 - For cube:**

```
if(int(x**(1./3.))**3 == int(x))
```

and **2 - For square:**

```
if(int(x**0.5)**2 ==int(x))
```

Take square root or cube of number convert to an integer then take the square or cube if the numbers are equal then it is a perfect square or cube otherwise not.

Answer (score 1):

Once you start working with floating point, you need to realise that infinite precision is not available. Often times, floating point values are really just the best approximation given the limited number of bits available for storing information.

For this particular case, you may find you can just take the integral values around the cube root, and check if cubing it gives you the original value.

Something like this should be a good start:

```
def is_cube(n):
    guess = n**(1.0/3.0)
    iguess = int(guess)
    if iguess * iguess * iguess == n:
        print(True, "the cubed root is", iguess)
        return
    iguess = iguess + 1
    if iguess * iguess * iguess == n:
        print(True, "the cubed root is", iguess)
        return
    print(False, "the cubed root is", guess)
```